# Rotational and translational angular momenta of a rigid body when they are in different direction

Tags: angular-momentum

can I find the angular momentum of a rigid body undergoing translation and rotation by simply adding the angular momentum of its center of mass as a point particle vectorally to the spin angular momentum ,when they are in different directions, and get a valid result for the total angular momentum of the body?

Answer (score 0):

I’d say the answer is yes, but it is a bit too vague. To be clear: any way where it works right to add, it also works right to subtract. Going the same way will never be required or make it different.

But to be clear about how they *do* add, you could always go through this:

Whenever talking about angular momentum, it’s important to know what is included in the rotating mass and what axis it is rotating about. The same object at the same angular velocity $\omega$ will have a different angular momentum around different axes.

But yes it’s still true that any system, seen from the outside, has one value for translation of its center, has rotation, and has moment of inertia.

---

Take a ball of radius $r$ connected to a thin, spinning center-post by string of length $R$, spinning at $\Omega$. Obviously the ball *revolves* at $\Omega$. Now imagine case 2 where a thin, light ball-bearing is connected to the string and the ball rotates within it.

Lookin down along the axis of rotation, draw an arrow ⬆️ on the top of the ball. In case 2 it always points the same way, and in case 1 it rotates once per revolution.

At the same angular velocity $\Omega$ of the system:
$$ v_1=v_2 =v= \Omega (R+r) $$ $$ \omega_1 = \Omega ~,~ \omega2 = 0$$

Here is how the angular momenta add up, case 1:

$$J_1= I_{tot} \Omega$$

$$\text{also }~J_1=I_{mass} \Omega+I_{ball} \omega_1$$

And $I_{tot}=I_{mass}+I_{ball}$

Where $I_{mass}$ is the moment of inertia of a point-mass in revolution, $m(R+r)^2$ in this case. And $I_{ball}$ is the moment of inertia of a sphere around around its axis. Clearly case 2 is

$$J_2= I_{mass} \Omega = m(R+r)^2 \Omega $$

---

Now that is the actual angular momentum of the system, and it’s velocity is zero. But we could have been saying it is translation and rotation. For example calculating energy

The kinetic energy in case 1 **is higher**: $$E_1= \frac{1}{2} m v^2 + \frac{1}{2} I_{ball} \omega^2$$.

**But didn’t we just say above there is zero velocity of this system??**

$$\text{also , }E_1=\frac{1}{2} I_{tot} \Omega^2$$

The second term is gone for case 2:
$$ E_2= \frac{1}{2} m v^2= \frac{1}{2} I_{mass} \Omega^2$$

$$\text{and , } E_1>E_2 ~,~ I_1 > I_2 ~,~ I_{tot}>I_{mass}$$